# How to limit the header to the page width?

Tags: header-footer

I have a long header and LaTeX inserts it broader than the page width.

[image: output]

How do make the header fit on the page?

Comment: use `\section[short title]{Evaporation... long title....}`

Comment: Please add [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that). ‘header’ can mean several things, please specify exactly what you mean.

Answer (score 2):

As David Carlisle points out in his comment, you can provide a shorter version of the chapter (or section) title by using their optional arguments.

However, this will also affect your table of contents which makes use of this optional argument, too.

If you want to give a short title only for the page heading, you need to use `\markboth` and `\markright`:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{book}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\chapter[I am a chapter title]{I am a chapter title and i am making use of the optional argument which will affect the table of contents}

Blindtext\newpage Blindtext\newpage Blindtext\newpage Blindtext\newpage

\chapter{I am a chapter title that is way to long to fit into the page heading without some extra coding}
\markboth{I am an even page title}{I am an odd page title}

Blindtext\newpage Blindtext\newpage Blindtext\newpage Blindtext\newpage

\section{I am a section title that is way to long to fit into the page heading without some extra coding}

Blindtext\newpage Blindtext\newpage Blindtext\newpage Blindtext\newpage Blindtext

\markright{I am markright}
\section{I am another section title that is way to long to fit into the page heading without some extra coding}
\markright{I am the second markright}

Blindtext\newpage Blindtext\newpage Blindtext\newpage Blindtext\newpage Blindtext

\end{document}
```

As you will notice, the first occurrence of `\section` overrides your `\markboth` for odd pages. In that case, you can use markright to redefine the running title for over-long section titles. Unfortunately, `\markright` will work only for pages that `follow` the page that includes the section, therefore you will need another `\markright` for the `\section`-bearing page itself which must occur *between* the page break and `\section`.

Play around with (un)commenting some of the `mark`-macros to figure out how they work.

Answer (score 0):

and in case you need to change the text, as read in post by Piet van Oostrum you can try to set a macro (coding `\renewcommand`) at the beginning of your document (after `\chapter` and after `\section`) or at the beginning of each file to specify header output. In this way you will overcome fancyhdr limitations.

Hope it helps!
Have a nice day.

MC